# Where does the Unity Dash get its launchers from?

Tags: launcher, wine, unity-dash

I created a launcher for Notepad++ (using [wine-launcher-creator](http://code.google.com/p/wine-launcher-creator/)) and moved it into `/usr/share/applications` and it's worked, except there are two identical entries in there now.

How can I track down where the duplicate is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash also looks in `~/.local/share/applications`, so you might want to check in there too.

Comment: That was it. Wine had added in some launchers for common file extensions as well as Notepad++. Removed them and now there's just one in the dash. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where they are stored, but I do know how you can add a launcher.

If you use wine for Notepad++ and have a launcher already, just dragging the executable to the launcher should be enough.